# Splunk :: Search String with Special Character

Tags: splunk

I am trying to below search String in splunk

`index=imdc_vms sourcetype=hadoop:app:compass:services TimeoutException with args[/mapr`

but it is giving error message

**Error in 'SearchParser': Missing a search command before '/'. Error at position '88' of search query 'search index=imdc_vms sourcetype=hadoop:app:compas...{snipped} {errorcontext = with args[/mapr}**'.

Can you please help to resolve this . I understand this is happening because of presence of forward slash "/" but even escape sequence similar to other language did not worked in splunk .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting the last part of the search string:

```
index=imdc_vms sourcetype=hadoop:app:compass:services "TimeoutException with args[/mapr"
```